# Objective C: Gif Conversion with with image array

Tags: ios, objective-c

For gif conversion with `ImageArray` . But I'm facing memory Issue when array contains more then 420 images (approximate).
Here is my code:

```
-(void) createGifFromImages:(NSArray*)imageArray :(NSString*)filename
{

    NSDictionary *fileProperties = @{
                                     (id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                             (id)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount: @0, // 0 means loop forever
                                             }
                                     };
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];

    filename=[filename stringByAppendingString:@".gif"];
    fileURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    NSLog(@"%@",fileURL);
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, kUTTypeGIF,imageArray.count, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (CFDictionaryRef)fileProperties);

    UIImage *image;
    for (int i=0;i<imageArray.count;i++) {
        image=imageArray[i];
        NSDictionary *frameDurationProperties = @{
                                                  (id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                                          (id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: _durationArray[i % _durationArray.count], // a float (not double!) in seconds, rounded to centiseconds in the GIF data
                                                          }
                                                  };
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameDurationProperties);
    }

    if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
    }

    CFRelease(destination);

}
```

In this code i'm using default size image.
How do I reduce my memory allocation?
& Is there any way to reduce size of images without changing its quality?

Comment: don't store the image in the array

Comment: you should store the asset link of the images in the array and then fetch each image through the asset link to make the gif

Comment: what is the problem if i store image??

Comment: it would go out of memory

Comment: actually  i spilt  the gif into images

Comment: then i fetch the images

Comment: so why do you want to convert it back to gif??

Comment: if anyone add text on gif for updating gif